# "18rjmp command assembly" in AVR Assembly

Tags: assembly, avr

I am looking at some AVR assembly code and I'm not sure what the following means.

The code defines a few registers using .equ directives e.g.

```
.equ rWork1, 21
.equ rWork2, 22
```

To my understanding, these are just memorable names for registers 21 and 22. Just earlier, the code defines the following between the names for `r17` and `r19`:

```
.equ rFast, 18rjmp command assembly
```

What does this mean? Why is `18rjmp` one word, and what does `command assembly` mean? Also, why might it be called `rFast`?

`rFast` is later used just as any other register.

Comment: What assembler is this for?  Probably GAS, given the `.equ` syntax, except I think it would complain about that.   How is the `rFast` symbol used later, and what does that usage assemble to?  (e.g. find an example where it's used, and check the machine code + disassembly there.  Probably a useful way to figure out what's going on, and if this is even valid.)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not acceptable by AVR studio.
This is closed code what AVR studio can accept to compile

```
.equ rWork1= 21  ;define a constant rWork with value 21
.equ rFast= 18rjmp command   ;two statements on one line, 
                             ;first define a constant rFast with value 18
                             ;second is instruction relative jump to label command

main:
    rjmp    main
command: 
    rjmp    main
```

`18rjmp` is not one token. 18 is number. Any character different from digit end number token. Parser then read next token `rjmp` as normal instruction.

Two (or more) statements per line is possible but not recommended in normal code.
Please read [AVRASM2 manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/40001917a.pdf#page=13) section 4.7

> AVRASM2 allows multiple instructions and directives per line, but its use is not recommended. It is
> needed to support expansion of multiline preprocessor macros.